# how i can load viewController instead of xib file

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2

well i want create notification button when the user click it will show for him viewcontroller or something

i found this library

https://github.com/lucaslt89/PopupContainer

the main problem that you can implement from xib file nib file and only UIView

it's possible  to load from Controller from Main Storyboard ?

this is the code

```
@IBAction func showFromXibButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let xibView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("XibPopup", owner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! XibPopup
    PopupContainer.generatePopupWithView(xibView).show()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by passing the view of the viewcontroller which you can get from the storyboard.

Example

```
@IBAction func showFromXibButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myViewController") as! UIViewController
    PopupContainer.generatePopupWithView(vc.view).show()
}
```

Please assign a proper ViewController Identifier in the storyboard and update the same in the code with the proper storybaord name

Updated the code as per question requirement by checking Hunter's format

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your storyboard is named "Main", and you have an initial view controller, this will would load the view from that controller:

```
@IBAction func showFromXibButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let controller = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController()
    PopupContainer.generatePopupWithView(controller!.view).show()
}
```

Note, it would be best practice to change the name of the IBAction to showFromViewControllerButtonPressed, but the above name will work.